# Using JS with Amazon Turk?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I've been asked to build a mturk HIT with some scripted behavior, e.g. show and hide content at different time intervals (let's say, for example, that a question would display an image for 5 seconds and then hide it).

A couple questions:

1. Is there a way to include javascript in HITs?
2. If not, is there a way to generate this kind of behaviour using the mturk API?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use an ExternalQuestion.  mturk does let you embed your own javascript inline, but it's not ideal.